# Return null value for Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
Date finalexamDate = Person.stream()
    .map(PersonDetails::getexamDate)
    .max(Date::compareTo)
    .orElse(null);
```

The following code produces a

> null pointer exception

as this person doesnt have any `getexamdate` during this case I wanted to return `null` to the `finalexamDate`

Tried adding `Optional.ofNullable` still produces the same error.

How should this be handled ? is there any way to handle along with the same line of code rather than checking one more `if condition` ?

Comment: Use Optional.empty(), returning to Optional<Date>.

Comment: Try adding `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` before your `max` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max` terminal method throws a Null pointer Exception if the maximum value is null . So it is safe to filter the values first so that the stream will only have non null values in it.

```
Date finalexamDate = Person.stream()
    .map(PersonDetails::getexamDate)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .max(Date::compareTo)
    .orElse("some default value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Ananth it worked